# How to parse the json data using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've been messing around with JSON for some time. I want to get the values of "box" and "text" in this format using python can someone help me out how to resolve this example output:[92,197,162,215,AUTHORS,...!]

```
{ "form": [ { "box": [ 92,162,197,215], "text": "AUTHORS", "label": "question", "words": [ { "box": [ 92,197,162,215 ],"text": "AUTHORS"} ], "linking": [[0,13]],"id": 0 },


        
import os
import json

# Directory name consisting of json
file = open('033.json')
data = json.load(file)



result = []
for value in data['form']:
    my_dict=[]
    my_dict=value.get('box')
    print(my_dict)
    result.append(my_dict)
```

Comment: What is the input data a d what have you tried so far?

Comment: look into `json.loads`

Comment: please provide more information so ppl can help you, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: { "form": [ { "box": [ 92,162,197,215], "text": "AUTHORS", "label": "question", "words": [ { "box": [ 92,197,162,215 ],"text": "AUTHORS"} ], "linking": [[0,13]],"id": 0 },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably like this:

```
collector = []
for obj in form:
    collector.append({"box": obj["box"], "text": obj["text"]})

print(collector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, few issues with your code -

1. Why is your list named `my_dict`? A name should indicate what the object is/ what it contains. Your name does the opposite and if someone works with that code in the future then it will most likely confuse them.
2. Why are you initializing a list before doing this `value.get('box')`?

As for the solution, it is a short piece of code that would require 2 lines of code.

```
result = []
for form_dict in data['form']:
    result.append(tuple(form_dict[key]
                        for key in ('box', 'text') if key in form_dict))
```

That piece of code would result in this: `[([92, 162, 197, 215], 'AUTHORS')]` based on the data you provided.
This is assuming that there can be more items in the `data['form']` list, otherwise the `for` loop is not needed.